# c# lambda get the latest items on the generic list if the item is duplicate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, lambda

I want to remove the old item from the list if there's a duplicate.

Here's my sample list:

```
1         Item1       Apr 27, 2013        $100
2         Item2       Apr 25, 2013        $200
3         Item3       Apr 24, 2013        $150
4         Item1       Apr 26, 2013        $100
5         Item3       Apr 25, 2013        $150
```

My Expected Result would be:

```
1         Item1       Apr 27, 2013        $100
2         Item2       Apr 25, 2013        $200
5         Item3       Apr 25, 2013        $150
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to get new list, with only proper elements:

```
var items = source.GroupBy(x => x.Item)
                  .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).First())
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: If the structure is a defined class instead of a generic query it must implement GetHashCode/Equals in order for the GroupBy to work.

Comment: @amhed It true, but to a property you're grouping with, not an object itself. I assumed the `Item` columns is a string, so it will work out of the box.